# TextView with setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS) firing android.util.AndroidRuntimeException when tapping the link

Tags: android, exception, hyperlink, textview

I'm inflating views programatically and I need the links inside the `TextViews` to be clickable.

I'm doing it this way:

```
((TextView) newView).setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
((TextView) newView).setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

But when I tap a link, this `Exception` is thrown:

> Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
>
> E/MessageQueue-JNI: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException:
>
> Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires
>   the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably passed the "wrong" context in your adapter. Here is a helpful article: https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: I'm not using any adapter, but you're right. I was using `ApplicationContext` instead of an `Activity`context. Thanks!